# K&R exercise question to an answer about the original question

Tags: c, macros, function-calls

I kept trying to wrap my head around a solution to K&R problem 7-8, until I found [this solution (with the original problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169261/c-isupper-function) right on this site. I am unable to comment on the answer (probably due to its age); the only way I could actually have input in that question is to post an answer to it, which I felt was inappropriate. So i've decided to create this heavily related question based off the chosen "answer" which seemed logical to me, up until I got up to this point (concerning implementing a function as a macro):

> *"Repeat that as a macro very often and the 'space saving' rapidly becomes a cost as the bit masking has a fixed size."*

The only problem is that function calls take time as well. "Jumping" to the function location, setting storage aside for the local variable(s), then actually computing the comparison, all take time.

So how exactly is implementing a macro which tests for the ASCII value of the character slower than the first function which incorporates table-lookup (with this in mind)?

How is it possible that a function call can take less time than comparing two integers, one of which is already in memory, and one of which is a constant? It would seem to me that repeated calls to the function and macro, over time, would still result in the macro being faster.

Is my way of thinking wrong? I'm thinking it has to be since it wasn't brought up in the original question.

I would be glad if someone would shed some light on this.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, note that the cost they mention is *size*, not speed. Just for example, let's assume that the macro expands to 16 bytes of code. Let's further assume that the function compiles to 32 bytes of code, and calling the function takes 6 bytes of code (of course, none of these is guaranteed, but they're all probably at least in the general ballpark of correct for 32-bit code).

In this case, if you use a function, but only call it from one place, you end up with 38 bytes of code. If you use the macro instead you only get 16 bytes of code, for a savings of 22 bytes. If you use the macro in two places, you get 32 bytes of code, vs., 44 bytes if you'd used a function -- still a savings, but a smaller one. Jumping ahead a bit, let's assume you used it from 10 different places in your code. In this case, the macro would take 160 bytes, but the function would only take 92 bytes.

On a modern processor, I can also see a fairly reasonable argument that a function could be faster as well though. Most modern processors use caching. If you use the function enough that it's usually going to be in the cache when you call it, that can well be faster than using a macro, where each time you use the code, you're (more) likely to have to fetch the code from memory again. The reason is pretty simple: a modern processor runs a *lot* faster than memory.

Even at best, you can plan on a latency of at least 50 ns to fetch some data from memory (and 75-100 ns is fairly common). Just as an average let's assume 75 ns. A typical modern CPU executes around 1.8 instructions per clock, and at (say) 2.5 GHz, has a clock cycle time of .4 ns. That means in 75 ns, it can (on average) execute something like 75/0.4*1.8 = 337.5 instructions. Calling, executing, and returning from a function like we're talking about here is somewhere on the order of a half dozen instructions -- so in a tight loop, by the time you'd fetched the code for the macro from memory once you could execute the function from the cache somewhere around 56 times.

Of course, if you're executing only that in a tight loop, the macro will be in the cache most of the time too. The advantage for the function happens when you have calls to that function from enough different places in the code that it'll usually be in the cache even on the *first* iteration of a loop, which usually won't be the case for a macro.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The original question implied that there were different options that either save space, or time (which I took to mean speed). Forgoing loops (although you are correct in that sense), lets talk about the function at hand (isupper). Supposing that calls to this function are randomly, sparsely scattered throughout the program (so the code for it wouldn't be in the cache), would a pure function implementation (implementing table lookup) be faster than a macro (implementing ASCII comparisons) considering the time to call the "real" func, or would it be the other way around?

Comment: @Kevin, If the function is used rarely enough to characterize it as "sparsely scattered", then it is almost certainly not a bottleneck, or even a noticeable contributor to your run time. Be careful that you aren't falling into the trap of premature optimization.

Comment: @Kevin, There's another advantage to the function. This is a standard library routine, which on modern systems is supplied by a DLL or .so. That means that the page containing this function and its lookup table can exist once in physical memory but be used by any number of processes. Performance in one process can be influenced by all the other processes that are tickling it, keeping the page in physical memory, and possibly even keeping the relevant bits in cache. This can be *very* hard to analyze.

Comment: @RBerteig: Thanks for your analysis. Its become clear to me that a function implementation is obviously the right way to go for "real world use", but I was more-so referring to a "laboratory test" of sorts which just compares the two options without factors such as cache and other processes (I believe that was what the K&R question was getting at as well). I guess what I'm looking for is something like: "purely the function, even with the call time, is faster than ASCII comparisons", but I don't see how that could be true. Nonetheless, great answers guys. More thoughts are welcome!