# C programming warning: array subscript has type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, char, subscript

I can't seem to fix this problem. Below is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

_Bool are_anagrams (const char *word1, const char *word2);

int main (void)
{
    char an1[30], an2[30];
    int j;
    printf("Enter first word: ");
    scanf("%s", an1);
    printf("Enter second word: ");
    scanf("%s", an2);
    printf("The words are");

    j = are_anagrams (an1, an2);

    if (j == 0)
    {
        printf(" not anagrams. \n");
    }else
        printf(" anagrams. \n");

    return 0;
}

_Bool are_anagrams (const char *word1, const char *word2)
{
    int i;
    int check[26] = {0};
    for(i=0; i<30; i++)
        if(word1[i] == '\0')
            i=40;
        else
        {
            word1[i] = toupper(word1[i]);
            check[word1[i]-65]++;
        }

    for(i=0; i<30; i++)
        if(word2[i] == '\0')
            i=40;
        else
        {
            word2[i] = toupper(word2[i]);
            check[word2[i]-65]--;
        }

    for(i=0; i<26; i++)
        if(check[i] != 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

    return 1;
}
```

these are the error messages:

```
anagram1.c:38:3: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
   word1[i] = toupper(word1[i]);
   ^
anagram1.c:38:3: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*(word1 + (sizetype)((long unsigned int)i * 1ul))’
anagram1.c:46:4: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
    word2[i] = toupper(word2[i]);
    ^
anagram1.c:46:4: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*(word2 + (sizetype)((long unsigned int)i * 1ul))’
```

Comment: `word1` and `word2` are pointers to `const char`.

Comment: check[toupper(word1[i])-65]++;
check[toupper(word2[i])-65]--;

Comment: I don't get that warning. The only warning I see is you trying to overwrite a const.

Comment: Those errors are understandable, but those warnings are wild, those subscripts are `int`, not `char`.

Comment: What is the significance of the number `65`? I think I know the answer to that, but there's a much clearer way to write it. Hint: Character constants are of type `int`.

Answer (score 5):

The warnings:

```
warning: array subscript has type ‘char’
```

are a result of 'toupper()' requiring an 'int' type as a parameter, while the question code is providing a 'char' type.

```
word1[i] = toupper(word1[i]);
...
word2[i] = toupper(word2[i]);
```

To eliminate the warning, give toupper() 'int' values:

```
word1[i] = toupper((unsigned char)word1[i]);
...
word2[i] = toupper((unsigned char)word2[i]);
```

To be thorough, you can cast the values returned by 'toupper()' from 'int' back to 'char':

```
word1[i] = (char)toupper((unsigned char)word1[i]);
...
word2[i] = (char)toupper((unsigned char)word2[i]);
```

---

The errors:

```
error: assignment of read-only location
```

are a result of trying to modify a value with a 'const' flag:

```
_Bool are_anagrams (const char *word1, const char *word2)
```

If appropriate, you can eliminate the errors by eliminating the 'const' flags:

```
_Bool are_anagrams (char *word1, char *word2)
```

Or, you can make local-working copies of the 'const' strings:

```
_Bool are_anagrams (const char *I__word1, const char *I__word2)
   {
   int rCode = 0;
   int i;
   int check[26] = {0};
   char *word1 = strdup(I__word1);
   char *word2 = strdup(I__word2);

   for(i=0; i<30; i++)
      if(word1[i] == '\0')
         i=40;
      else
         {
         word1[i] = toupper(word1[i]);
         check[word1[i]-65]++;
         }

   for(i=0; i<30; i++)
      if(word2[i] == '\0')
         i=40;
      else
         {
         word2[i] = toupper(word2[i]);
         check[word2[i]-65]--;
         }

   for(i=0; i<26; i++)
      if(check[i] != 0)
        goto CLEANUP;

   rCode=1;

CLEANUP:
   free(word2);
   free(word1);

   return(rCode);
   }
```

***NOTE: The above code uses the the question code body, which may or may not be accurate.  This answer has no intention to fix other issues in the question code; only to demonstrate a proper method to work around the 'const' flags on the parameters by creating non-'const' copies of the parameters***

Comment: I have a requirement of having the 'const' flag. Any way to bypass this? Or do I have to rewrite the program?

Comment: Why assign to word1 and word2 for no reason at all?

Comment: Your first part, about `toupper`, is just plain wrong. First, a char is promoted to an int for parameter passing anyway; second, an array call like that has absolutely nothing to do with array subscripting.

Comment: @Kevin, you are correct.  I try to refrain from completing homework; just answering the question at hand.  I edited the answer, and added a note to clarify that intent.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I said. Your first sentence, "The warnings:

warning: array subscript has type ‘char’
are a result of 'toupper()' requiring an 'int' type as a parameter, while the question code is providing a 'char' type" is wrong. While `toupper` does require an int, the char is promoted, and the error would not say anything about subscripting if that were the problem.

Comment: If you promote a negative plain `char` to `int`, you keep the sign, which is no help.  You must cast to `unsigned char`, and then let the compiler convert that to `int`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I -think- I understand now.  I edited the answer; is it more correct now?  (I can't get my gcc to emit the warning in any case?)

Comment: Yup — definitely better.  I think that making a full copy of the strings is still overkill (which I didn't mention before), but it is now technically correct.

Comment: @Kevin , you were right.  I was definitely 'out in the weeds'.  Thank you for catching my incompetence.  Good job!

Answer (score 2):

The `toupper` and `tolower` functions declared in `<ctype.h>` (along with the `is*()` functions) expect an argument of type `int`.

The type isn't the problem, since `char` will be implicitly converted to `int`. The problem is that the *value* they expect must be either within the range of `unsigned char` *or* the value `EOF` (typically `-1`). We can ignore the `EOF` case.

Plain `char` is either signed or unsigned, at the whim of your compiler developer (guided by your system's ABI).  If plain `char` is signed, and the value you pass to `toupper` happens to have a negative value (that doesn't happen to equal `EOF`), then you have undefined behavior.

The solution is to explicitly convert (cast) the argument to `unsigned char`.

Rather than:

```
word1[i] = toupper(word1[i]);
```

you need to write:

```
word1[i] = toupper((unsigned char)word1[i]);
```

Yes, it's unfortunate that you have to do this. It would be better if `toupper()` simply took an argument of type `char` and returned a `char` result. But this is the way it is, and we're stuck with it.

So why did you get a warning about an array subscript of type `char`? The `toupper` function is commonly implemented as a macro that expands to an array indexing operation. After the preprocessor expands the macro invocation, it no longer looks (to the rest of the compiler) like a function call. (Any standard library function can be implemented as a macro, as long as the macro has the same behavior that an actual function call would have.)

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that every standard library function can *also* be implemented as a macro as long as the macro has the same behaviour. If `Converter` is an appropriate function pointer type, then `Converter xform = &toupper; char c = xform(i);` has to work and do the same thing as `char c = toupper(i);`.

Answer (score 2):

As [Mahonri Moriancumer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3525545/mahonri-moriancumer) correctly identifies in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23506934/15168) (and, indeed, as [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) correctly identified and explained in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23507447/15168)), the problem with the calls to `toupper()` is that the type you're passing is `char` yet the functions expect an `int`.  But since an `int` can contain any value that a `char` can contain, why is it complaining?

The answer is that the range of valid `int` values is restricted by the standard (ISO/IEC 9888:2011):

> #### 7.4 Character handling `<ctype.h>`
>
> In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be
>   representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the
>   argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

What the compiler is warning you is that if you pass a `char` to this function, and if the `char` type is a signed type, then you may be passing an index that is negative.  The result of `getchar()`, `getc()` or `fgetc()` matches the specification of the argument type for the functions (and this is not an accident).  The compiler assumes you won't pass out of bounds values if you use an `int`, but if you use plain `char` to hold characters such as 'Å' (U+00C5, LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE) and plain `char` is signed, then you will be passing a negative value well outside the range of valid values.

If it were my code, I would cast to `unsigned char`:

```
word1[i] = toupper((unsigned char)word1[i]);
```

Simply casting a signed plain `char` to `int` doesn't deal with the sign properly.

You can review [C `isupper()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169261/c-isupper-function/2169293#2169293) to understand more about why the ranges are set as they are.

---

The other pair of errors comes because you modify a constant string.  You can avoid that error (for unaccented characters) with:

```
unsigned char uc = word1[i];
if (isalpha(uc))
    check1[toupper(uc) - 'A']++;
```

This avoids problems with spaces, digits and punctuation in the input.  However, if you need to deal with accented characters in the input, then your best bet is to make `check` into an array of size 256, and then check over the whole range 0..255 that the counts are the same.

Comment: Is there anything here that I didn't cover in my answer?

Comment: No; probably not — that's why you've got an up-vote.  Or yes, the quote from the standard, and sample character values, and other minor details. Your answer arrived while I was typing mine (and I didn't spot it until after I'd hit submit); independent statements of the same facts are going to look similar.