# C: String functions without string.h library

Tags: c, string

I have homework to do and I need some help. I didn't come here to get someone to do my work, just to help me.

I have to create my own string.h "library" (actually header and function file), so I am **forbidden** to use **`#include <string.h>` and `#include <ctypes.h>`**. They also recommended us not to use malloc, but it was just a recommendation, not forbidden. 
For most of the functions I know how to write them.
I planned to save "strings" like arrays of chars like:

```
char array[50];
```

But I came to a problem of creating toupper and tolower functions.
Sure, I can make huge switch cases or a lot if (else if's) like this:

```
if(string[i]=='a') {string[i]=='A' };
 else if(string[i]=='b') {string[i]=='B' };
    .
    .
    .
    else if(string[i]=='z') {string[i]=='Z' };
```

But is there any better solution?

Strings are going to be created **randomly** so they will look somewhat like this:

```
ThisISSomESTRing123.
```

So after `toupper` function, randomly generated string should look like this:

```
THISISSOMESTRING123.
```

Also how would you create `puts` function (printing) so everything would be in same row? Just "printf" inside "for" loop?

Comment: Try looking at the ASCII codes for upper and lower case letters, and you should spot a pattern.

Comment: Do you know about arrays yet?  You want to make a table so you can look up one piece of information ('a') and retrieve another piece of information ('A').  I'll leave it to you to figure out how.

Comment: Maybe [C `isupper()` function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169261) can help?

Comment: And while ASCII covers some character sets, it doesn't cover the majority of real-world character sets.  In particular, all the solutions mentioning ASCII that I've seen won't work on accented characters.

Comment: For a better understanding of the concepts, you could read the [Unicode FAQ on Case Mapping](http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html). (And to properly *implement* it - most likely outside the target of your exercise - you would need to include the entire current Unicode standard.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your system probably uses ASCII. In ASCII, the codepoints of lowercase characters and uppercase characters are sequential.

So we can just do:

```
void to_upper(char *message) {
    while (*message) {
        if (*message >= 'a' && *message <= 'z')
            *message = *message - 'a' + 'A';
        message++;
    }   
}
```

Other character encodings can become **much more complicated**. For example, EBCDIC doesn't have contiguous characters. And UTF-8 introduces a world of problems because of the numerous languages that you need to support.

Comment: Thank you very much! ASCII came in mind to me, but I didn't know you can use it that way.

Answer (score 3):

You can just check if the character is within the range of characters, say between 'a' and 'z' and just add or subtract 32, which is the difference between the ascii value of capital and lower letters.  See the ascii table here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
if (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z') {
    string[i] = string[i] - 'a' + 'A';
}
```

It will convert lower case to upper case by changing a..z to 0..26 then adding the ASCII value for 'A' to it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a neat trick for converting ASCII cases. Consider these characters:

`A` - binary `01000001`
`a` - binary `01100001`

As we can see, the difference is in the 6th bit, counting from the right. Indeed, the difference between uppercase and lowercase ASCII chars is 2^5 = 32. So, to convert a letter to uppercase, simply AND it with `0xDF (11011111)` to set that bit to 0. In this way you don't even have to check if the character is in uppercase already.

Note that this will break non-letter characters that are above `0x60`, namely the backtick, `{`, `|`, `}` and `~`. But as long as you don't have these in your strings, it should be fine to use this and you can avoid an `if` :).

Note: Only use that as a cool trick for this homework. Normally you should just use proper, tested solutions (aka `string.h`).

Comment: Nice trick - but regarding _and you can avoid an if_...  checking the range of character before applying is still required, which likely will get back to using the `if` keyword.

Comment: @ryyker Nope, that is the point - you do not need to check the range as long as you're sure the five characters I've enumerated in my answer don't appear in your string. That bit will then only be set for lowercase ASCII letters, which is what you want to convert; for all other chars, that bit will be 0 anyway, so it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
void toUpper(char *arr) {
    while (*arr) {
        if (*arr >= 'a' && *arr <= 'z')
            *arr = *arr - 'a' + 'A';
        arr++;
    }   
   }
```

use this function to make all the letters uppercase in a string just call the toUpper funcn and give your array as a prarameter.
for printing the array just use for loop and move in array index elements and print the letters.

```
   for(int i=0;arr[i] !='\0';i++)
   {
    printf("%c",arr[i]);
   }
```

this will print every elements in the array which is the string,

Comment: Your first code snippet is identical to the accepted answer posted more than 4 years before (only the variable name is different). And regarding your second code snippet... why not just use `printf("%s", arr)` or `puts(arr)`? What does this answer add to the already posted answers?